# how to define an index in the graphML format?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graphml

i exported my data into graphML format, and want to import them into neo4j via gremlin's graphML.import() function. i need to create indexes to index all my imported data. is it even possible in the graphML format?

my export xml looks like this:

```
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
        http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">

<key id="user" for="node" attr.name="user" attr.type="int" />
<key id="item" for="node" attr.name="item" attr.type="int" />
<graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
....
</graph>
</graphml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,
GrapmML does not contain this. You could enable autoindexes on the fields you want before you start the import, so they are recording the changes fro you? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/auto-indexing.html

Comment: yes, i was thinking about the autoindexing, but my point was to have an easy way of export/import data without additional setup. but thanks, at least i'll not spend time with graphML anymore.